# Create tree structure in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this :

```
var data = [
     {name:'hello',image:'',children:[]},
     {name:'hello2',image:'',children:[]},
     {name:'hello3',image:'',children:[]},
     {name:'hello4',image:'',children:[]}
];
```

I want to convert to this :

```
var data = [{
  name: 'hello',
  image: '',
  children: [{
    name: 'hello2',
    image: '',
    children: [{
      name: 'hello3',
      image: '',
      children: [{
        name: 'hello4',
        image: '',
        children: [{
          name: 'hello5',
          image: '',
          children: []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: @FelixKling 
i can just create one level of tree structure.
But now with Pranav C Balan code, i can solved problem.
than you!!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a simple `for` loop.

```
var data = [
     {name:'hello',image:'',children:[]},
     {name:'hello2',image:'',children:[]},
     {name:'hello3',image:'',children:[]},
     {name:'hello4',image:'',children:[]}
];

for(var i=0; i<data.length-1; i++){
    var currentData= data[i];
    currentData.children.push(data[i+1]);
}
data.splice(1, data.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple like this using a [while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) and **[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method.

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'hello',
  image: '',
  children: []
}, {
  name: 'hello2',
  image: '',
  children: []
}, {
  name: 'hello3',
  image: '',
  children: []
}, {
  name: 'hello4',
  image: '',
  children: []
}];

// variable to hold the inner object
var obj = data[0];

// iterate upto array become only one element
while (1 < data.length) {
  // push to children array the next array element
  obj.children.push(data.splice(1, 1)[0])
  // update obj with reference of inner object
  obj = obj.children[0];
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a potential use case for [**`reduceRight`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight). You simply have to add the previous value as child to the next value:

```
data = data.reduceRight((previous, current) => (current.children.push(previous), current));
```

I'm not seeing a reason to have an array at the top level, but that easily to achieve as well.